# Unique ID from two ids in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, insert-into

I need to create a unique Identification number for each entry in a table. Two entries, name and nickname are provided and the database query needs to be made in such a way that name is entered as unique id if it is present, otherwise nickname is entered into the database column. If both name and nickname are present, name is entered into the database. 
eg:

```
Name: Ritika
Nickname: Rits

Name: Pooja
Nickname: 

Name: 
Nickname: Fanny

Name: Rahul
Nickname: Rahi
```

For the above entries, the table formed should be:

[image: Mysql Table]

Is it possible to do such a thing? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: but do You need to create this id field in database or only select data so it shows id in your query result? Also, this empty field is null or just '' ?

Comment: I need to create an id field in the database, and empty fields are null values. But if that is not possible, i could do with the retrieval of the query too

Comment: I can't help thinking that, whatever you're actually trying to do, this sounds like a bad idea

Comment: this id need to be unique? Then how you be sure that 2 people doesn't share the same name.?

Comment: that I am ensuring using php. The thing is, unique idea without the actual name of the person is not possible in this case because these names later need to be compared with other names